# How to perform Gradient Check with Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

The represented *Neural Network* described here were created for image classification also for simple computing of Gradient Check for 1 hidden layer with 1 neuron using TensorFlow API.

The code bellow was based with the reference of the [TensorFlow Test Gradient Check example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/ops/gradient_checker_test.py)

```python
def check_gradients(feed_dict, num_features, neurons , output_size, cost):
    batch = len(feed_dict[images_placeholder])
    e = 1e-4

    all_params = [
        images_placeholder, #shape = (?,1024) ? == batch
        tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Layer_Hidden/weights:0'), #shape=(1024, 1) 
        tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Layer_Hidden/biases:0'), #shape=(1,)
        tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Layer_Output/weights:0'), #shape=(1, 10)
        tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Layer_Output/biases:0'), #shape=(10,)
    ]

    print (all_params[0])
    param_sizes = [
        [batch, num_features], # [100, 1024]
        [num_features, neurons],  # [1024, 1]
        [neurons],  # [1]
        [neurons, output_size],  # [1,10]
        [output_size], # [10]
    ]

    for param_index in range(len(all_params)):
        diff = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(
            all_params[param_index], 
            param_sizes[param_index], 
            cost,
            [batch],
            delta=e,
            extra_feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print('level:', param_index, ', Gradient Error:', diff)
```

Some important snippet code is shown to improve the understanding of the proposed struct:

```python
 images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024])
 batch = 100
```

The error for this calculation is related with `images_placeholder` shape as described above.

> InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 100 values,
>   but the requested shape has 1
>
> [[Node: gradients_1/Loss/Add_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
>   (gradients_1/Loss/Add_grad/Sum, gradients_1/Loss/Add_grad/Shape)]]

I could not figure out what's going wrong, for that I addressed this question here.

Thanks

Comment: You can probably find an error by printing the shapes of all inputs to `compute_gradient_error()` calls. Something like `print("expected size: " + str(param_sizes[param_index]) + ". actual size: " + str(all_params[param_index].get_shape()))` and comparing that they indeed match. You can also do the same for `cost` and `[batch]`.

Comment: Also, it would have been useful if you provided full stack trace and the `param_index` at which the error happened.